# How to get the unicode numbers of certain characters from a TTF font file?

Tags: python, unicode, fonts, chess

I am trying to modify this line of a python script about chess:

```
piece = dict(zip('KQRBNPkqrbnp',
                 [unichr(s) for s in range(ord(u'♔'), ord(u'♟') + 1)]))
```

Basically, the dictionary associates a character representing a chess piece to his unicode chess symbol. For example, K(King)--> ♔ and so on for every piece.

From wikipedia you can see the codes for these chess symbols:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode

The problem, is that I am using a custom TTF font which does not have the chess characters in the expected position.

I opened the font file with FontForge, but I can not understand the codes.

How can I find out right numbers of the chess symbols?

Comment: Why not produce a table of Unicode codepoints (numbers and the character) so you can figure this out by eye instead?

Comment: Actually it was easier than I thought. I just tried to write the characters in OpenOffice with the custon font and I found out the right codes.